# How do I know the thread id inside the function using NSPR threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sqlite

I am using [NSPR threads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NSPR_API_Reference/Threads) in my application. I am creating 50 threads. Each thread will open SQLite database and execute the query.

The function BusyHandler (in the program below) will be called when two threads executes the query at the same. How do we get the threadid inside the BusyHandler function?

Sample Program:

```
#define THREADCOUNT 50

static int BusyHandler(void * pArg, int pTries);

void CreateThreads()
{
    int i = 0;
    PRThread *thread[THREADCOUNT];

    for(i = 0; i<THREADCOUNT;i++)
    {
        waitobj[i] = new WaitObj();
        thread[i] = PR_CreateThread(PR_USER_THREAD, StartThread, (void *)i, PR_PRIORITY_NORMAL, PR_GLOBAL_THREAD, PR_JOINABLE_THREAD, 0);
    }

    Sleep(20000);
    for(i = 0; i<THREADCOUNT;)
    {     
       waitobj[i]->Signal();
       PR_JoinThread(thread[i]);    
       i = i+1;
    }
}
void StartThread(void *Arg)
{ 
    char *errmsg;
    const char *err;
    const char *unused;
    int ret;

    int index = (int)Arg;
    sqlite3 *sqlite;

    const char *dir = "test.sqlite";
    ret = sqlite3_open(dir, &sqlite);
    sqlite3_busy_handler(sqlite, BusyHandler, sqlite);

    char query[100];
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    strcpy(query, "insert into table1 values(1,2,3,4,5)");
    ret = ExecuteQuery(sqlite, query);
    if(ret != SQLITE_OK && ret != SQLITE_DONE )
    {       
        return;
    }
    Sleep(10000);   
}

int BusyHandler(void * pSQLite, int pTries)
{
    sqlite3 * sqlite = (sqlite3 *)pSQLite; 
    Sleep(1000);

    if(pTries >= 10) // now return BUSY
        return 0;

    // check whether lock is removed!
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Have you even tried googling this..? https://www.mozilla.org/projects/nspr/reference/html/prthrd.html#15202

Comment: On an unrelated subject: what's the point of doing it like this?

Comment: @lethal-guitar, GetCurrentThread returns the current thread object for the currently running code.

Comment: Yes, and this gives you the thread ID, doesn't it? "In NSPR, a thread is represented by a pointer to an opaque structure of type PRThread. ... The identifier remains valid until it returns from its root function" Also, regarding `GetCurrentThread` they say: "This is the only safe way to establish the identity of a thread."

Comment: @Dariusz Wawer, I want to stop the thread when main thread signals. If database is locked then BusyHandler will return only after 10 tries. In this case, thread will wait for BusyHandler to return. If I can identify the thread inside BusyHandler then we can check whether thread is signalled or not and return.